# How can I move the navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

Been working with a template and I want to try to move the navigation bar. But it dosen't seem that easy, seems like I'll have to change the CSS. Can anone help me here?

Here's the HTML and how the website looks so far:
[image]

I would like to move it to the left corner, and this is the CSS code I believe I can do the trick in:

```
    .header-nav {
    background: #0C0C0C;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    font-family: "montserrat-light", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    line-height: 1.846;
    padding: 3.6rem 3rem 3.6rem 3.6rem;
    height: 100%;
    width: 280px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 700;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    visibility: hidden;
}

.header-nav a, .header-nav a:visited {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.header-nav a:hover,
.header-nav a:focus,
.header-nav a:active {
    color: white;
}

.header-nav h3 {
    font-family: "montserrat-semibold", sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .25rem;
    margin-bottom: 4.8rem;
    margin-top: .9rem;
    color: #39b54a;
}

.header-nav p {
    margin-bottom: 2.7rem;
}

.header-nav__content {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
```

Would appreciate if anyone could help!

Comment: It would be better if you provided your HTML raw in the question opposed to in an image. This will make it easier for others to help answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your header-nav element is the hamburger icon, you can delete right:0 and set

```
.header-nav {
...
left:0;
...
}
```

Comment: This actually moved it. Howevert now the animation is wrong, it still comes from the right one. Do you know how I can change this aswell?

Comment: It is hard to know, without a snippet...., in your css code you can try setting transform: translateX(-100%); in your .header-nav..as I said I am guessing..

Comment: Hey there! Did the job! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I'm kinda new to all this, how do I mark it as correct?

Comment: Done! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

Add following css file to your project:
https://mladenplavsic.github.io/bootstrap-navbar-sidebar/navbar-fixed-left.min.css

And add the 'navbar-fixed-left' tag to your 'nav' element.

If you want to read everything about it here's the site:
https://mladenplavsic.github.io/bootstrap-navbar-sidebar/

You can find the code in the broncode of the page